# i got no error, but : "OleDbException was unhandled Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" how to solve this?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am new in creating an application using Visual Stuido 2010 C# and Microsft Access 2007. I am planning to create an application where the user can add data to the database(MS-Access). But I got an error stating that "Syntax Error (missing operator) In Query Expression". I really can't find what's the problem with my code. im using panel for page 2 of my form.

i got the problem from Sub Button1 "rd = cmd.ExecuteReader"
This is my code in adding data to the database:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim str As String
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim rd As OleDbDataReader
    Dim tanya As String

    Sub koneksi()
        str = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=Database1.mdb"
        conn = New OleDbConnection(str)
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
    End Sub


    Sub tampilkan()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tb_bpl", conn)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tb_bpl")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_bpl")
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 250
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call koneksi()
        Call tampilkan()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bersih()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        TextBox11.Text = ""
        TextBox12.Text = ""
        TextBox13.Text = ""
        TextBox14.Text = ""
        TextBox15.Text = ""
        TextBox16.Text = ""
        TextBox17.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * tb_bpl where periode='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If Not rd.HasRows Then 'jika data/baris tidak ditemukan
            Dim simpan As String = "insert into tb_bpl(periode, reviewer, pemeriksa, paraf1, paraf2, y1, kkp1, ket1, y2, kkp2, ket2, y3, kkp3, ket3, y4, kkp4, ket4) values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox13.Text & "','" & TextBox14.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "','" & TextBox16.Text & "','" & TextBox17.Text & "')"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(simpan, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Data Baru Tersimpan", vbInformation, "Pemberitahuan!!!")
            Call bersih()
        Else
            MsgBox("Data Sudah Ada", vbInformation, "Maaf!!!")
        End If
        tampilkan()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from tb_bpl where periode='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            Dim sqledit As String = "update tb_bpl set reviewer='" & TextBox2.Text & "',pemeriksa='" & TextBox3.Text & "',paraf1='" & TextBox4.Text & "',paraf2='" & TextBox5.Text & "',y1='" & TextBox6.Text & "' ,kkp1='" & TextBox7.Text & "' ,ket1='" & TextBox8.Text & "',y2='" & TextBox9.Text & "',kkp2='" & TextBox10.Text & "',ket2='" & TextBox11.Text & "',y3='" & TextBox12.Text & "',kkp3='" & TextBox13.Text & "',ket3='" & TextBox14.Text & "',y4='" & TextBox15.Text & "',kkp4='" & TextBox16.Text & "',ket4='" & TextBox17.Text & "'  where periode='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqledit, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        MsgBox("Data Terubah", vbOKOnly, "Sukses")
        Call bersih()
        Call tampilkan()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from tb_bpl where periode='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            tanya = MsgBox("Anda Yakin Akan Menghapus Data?", vbYesNo, "Perhatian")
            If tanya = vbYes Then
                Dim sqlhapus As String = "delete * from tb_bpl where periode='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlhapus, conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Data Terhapus", vbOKOnly, "Sukses")
                Call bersih()
            End If
        End If
        Call tampilkan()

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from tb_bpl where periode='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            TextBox2.Text = rd.Item("reviewer")
            TextBox3.Text = rd.Item("pemeriksa")
            TextBox4.Text = rd.Item("paraf1")
            TextBox5.Text = rd.Item("paraf2")
            TextBox6.Text = rd.Item("y1")
            TextBox7.Text = rd.Item("kkp1")
            TextBox8.Text = rd.Item("ket1")
            TextBox9.Text = rd.Item("y2")
            TextBox10.Text = rd.Item("kkp2")
            TextBox11.Text = rd.Item("ket2")
            TextBox12.Text = rd.Item("y3")
            TextBox13.Text = rd.Item("kkp3")
            TextBox14.Text = rd.Item("ket3")
            TextBox15.Text = rd.Item("y4")
            TextBox16.Text = rd.Item("kkp4")
            TextBox17.Text = rd.Item("ket4")
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Your query is missing a `FROM` clause: `select * FROM tb_bpl…`

Comment: thank you @Wolfgang Kais, idk why i still cant give rep or mark your correct answer, prolly because my acc still new..